# c++ std::map index variable

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, dictionary, indexing

Ive got a std::map setup like this:

```
static map<string, string> games;
```

Inside a for loop im trying to assign the variable to the index value like so

```
games[name] = "Yes!";
```

but that just gives me the error

```
136: error: no match for operator[] in games[name]
```

Comment: What is the type of `name` variable?

Comment: let's get the daft stuff out of the way, you've included `<map>` and somewhere you've declared `using std::map;`, and just to check one more thing, you've not declared `games` as some other type near the for loop?

Comment: Doh, you were right, i'd used games inside the loop when it should of been game. My fault for using stupid variable names, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible causes for that error:

1. The `games` variable is not an `std::map` instance.
2. The `name` variable is not an `std::string` instance.

Also, check if there are no name collisions.

Answer (score 0):

It's because 136 is not a String, but an integer value. The map you defined admits string keys, and string values only.

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

`name` is not a string variable, so it cannot find a matching [] operator - the only one present expects a string parameter.

The map's [] operator expects the key value in the [] - something you have defined as a string.

You could fake an integer index using the iterator operations.